# Selecting features by location in QGIS (boundaries_touches)

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, select-by-location, boundaries

Is there a tool or function in QGIS which can select features of one layer which are located on the boundaries of another layers features? In ArcGIS it's the "select features by location" tool and the relationship set to "boundaries_touches", but I need to work it into a QGIS Model for accessibility.

Edit:
The shapefile for the selection is a grid and looks like this:

[image: Grid]

The selection reference is the grid dissolved into Basins and looks like this:

[image: Basin]

The operation should select every feature/grid cell which touches the borders of the features of the basin shapefile.

Answer (score 3):

[Select by location](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-location) with `geometric predicate: cross`:

> Returns 1 (true) if the supplied geometries have some, but not all,
> interior points in common and the actual crossing is of a lower
> dimension than the highest supplied geometry.

[image]

---

Since your grid align perfectly with your big polygon you can:

1. Polygons to line on your big polygons
2. Buffer output
3. Select grids by location using you buffer as selection features
4. Unselect using a dissolved - polygons to line - buffered border
   [image]

Comment: That unfortunately did not work, it just selected every feature. I'm updating my question with some screenshots.

Comment: You want to select the small grids that lies on the border of the big polygons? That should work. Are your grid layer a big multipolygon (if you click and select one square you select all)? Are the big polygons created from the grid so the borders overlap perfectly?

Comment: The cells in the grid shapefile each have a seperate feature in the attribute table, they are not related to each other. If you select one of the cells it only selects the exact one in the attribute table. The big polygon shapefile is created on the basis of the grid shapefile so the align perfectly.

Comment: And yes exactly, that's what I'm trying to do!

Comment: Convert the big polygons to lines, buffer with a very small buffer, select by location

Comment: BERA's solution works perfectly. It would be great to have a built-in solution for this tough.